# Trying to wrap interactive report email column but doesn't work

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive report with column Email.

The column width is getting increased decreased using html but i am unable to wrap it.

The codes i have used till now:

CSS

```css
span.com-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

HTML

```html
<span style="display:block; width:200px; white-space:normal">
    #COLUMN_NAME_OF_REPORT#
</span>
```

The email id overflows if longer and doesn't break to next line as expected in wrap.

Apex version: 22.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you just remove everything you tried?

Because, if you leave it *as is*, Apex will automatically resize all columns to fit the screen (*responsive design*, eh?), and all "long" texts will be wrapped to as many lines as needed.

---

**[EDIT]**

As what I above suggested doesn't work as I thought it would (most probably because e-mail address is a being treated as a "single word" (there are no spaces within)), another option is to manually **split** e-mail address into two rows: the first would contain someone's "name", and another would represent "domain".

Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select e.*,
     --
     e.ename ||'.'|| e.job ||'@gmail.com' e_mail          --> this is e-mail address
     --           
   from emp e
   where rownum <= 5
  )
select t.empno, t.ename, t.job, t.sal,
  --
  substr(t.e_mail, 1, instr(t.e_mail, '@') - 1) ||        --> this is e-mail address 
  '<br>' ||                                               --> split into
  substr(t.e_mail, instr(t.e_mail, '@')) wrapped_email    --> two rows
  --
from temp t
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That isn't happening and unfortunately its prod data. cant share